# Is a Perl format bound to a file handle regardless of creation scope?

Tags: perl, format

I'd like to define a format to be used with a given file handle in the example Perl code below `$main_rpt_csv_fh`.

So, I believe my format statement would start out like this:

`format main_rpt_csv_fh =`

If I try to create this in a subroutine, does the creation of the format using the file_handle's name permanantly link the format to the file handle, or do the file handle and format have to be in the same scope?

Here is the code I've written so far.

```
my $main_rpt_path = "/home/ics/work/rpts/interim/mtr_prebill.rpt";

my $main_rpt_fh = undef;


open $main_rpt_fh, "> ", 
   $main_rpt_path or die "$main_rpt_path: $!";
```

The purpose of asking this, is I would like to keep my main Perl code neat, and the idea of creating the format in a subroutine would help.

Should the `format` statement go before or after the fh declaration and before the `open`, for example?

One final question. Are formats the best way to handle what I want, which is to create spreadhseet-like (formatted) data across like an old "greenbar" report? If not, what is the preferred way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One final question. Are formats the best way to handle what I want,
>   which is to create spreadhseet-like (formatted) data across like an
>   old "greenbar" report? If not, what is the preferred way?

From [Perl::Critic::Policy::Miscellanea::ProhibitFormats](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl%3a%3aCritic%3a%3aPolicy%3a%3aMiscellanea%3a%3aProhibitFormats):

> Formats are one of the oldest features of Perl. Unfortunately, they
>   suffer from several limitations. Formats are static and cannot be
>   easily defined at run time. Also, formats depend on several obscure
>   global variables.
>
> For more modern reporting tools, consider using one of the template
>   frameworks like Template or try the Perl6::Form module.

Comment: Aye, I was about to recommend [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl6::Form) (Perl6-syle forms for Perl5) too.

Answer (score 3):

Formats are global. As a result, there is some debate about removing them from the language.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about format. I've asked a final question in the OP w/o editing the original content. Would you consider editing your answer to include the answer to that final question? Thanks.